# Order a data set

Tags: r

I have a list of `dataframe` which I want to order according 3 column.

I've tried to apply an anonymous function

```
mylist<-lapply(mylist, function (x) x[order((data[,col1]),(data$namecol2),na.last=NA),])
```

I've tried in a loop :

```
for (i in 1:length(mylist)) {
  list_sorted <-mylist[[i]][order((data[,col1]),(data$namecol2),na.last=NA),]    
}
```

Either way I get a list of `dataframe` which are full of NA when they were not in the first place. This step create the `dataframe` full of NA, I checked the step before and it return my `dataframe` full of values.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to order based on 3 columns or the 3rd column?  In your code, you have two columns in the order function `x[order((data[,col1]),(data$namecol2)`.  Here `x` is the dataset or list element.  I don't understand where `data` came from.  I think it should be `x[order(x[,col],..`  Please provide a small example data

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a list with dataframes, and want to sort each of the dataframes based on a column in the dataframe.

The example I have below is a list with two dataframes, the dataframe consists of two columns("x" and "y"). And I sort it based on the column "x" in a descending order. Hope this gives you an idea to accomplish what you want.

```
x <- rep(1:5)
y <- rnorm(5)
dfrm <- data.frame(x,y)
str(dfrm)
names(dfrm)
listd <- list(dfrm,dfrm)
str(listd)
listsorted <- lapply(listd, function(z) z[with(z,order(x,decreasing=TRUE,na.last=NA)),])
listsorted
```

Comment: returns an error in the 'listsorted' assignment line

Comment: @ agenis - I corrected the function definition, the variable z was missing before the "[". Now it should work, I tested it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I finally managed doing it with the plyr package and arrange function which I lapply to my list.